# Why does sapply return a matrix when used with is.na on this data frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, apply, sapply

I'm trying to get a count of all the NAs present in columns of a data frame, and sapply() is returning a matrix. Same dimensions and everything and it's easy enough to call data.frame() on it afterward, but I'm curious why it does that. It seems that apply([df], 1, [is.na]) does the same thing. Any thoughts? Reproducible code below.

```
df1 <-data.frame(matrix(c(rep(c(1:10, NA), 9), NA), nrow = 10)) 
  #make a data frame with some NAs
df2 <- sapply(df1, is.na)
class(df2) 
  #returns "matrix"
df3 <- apply(df1, 1, is.na)
class(df3) 
  #also returns "matrix"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `lapply` operates on and coerces to lists, and `sapply` is a "simplified" form of `lapply` that tries to be convenient and coerce to a vector or matrix depending on the result.

From the docs:

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.
>   sapply is a “user-friendly” version of lapply by default returning a vector or matrix if appropriate.

Comment: ...and the corresponding direct quote from `?apply`: "If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.".